# All associations not being built

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

Is this a bug in Rails 7?

```rb
# user.rb
has_one :company
has_many :foos


# company.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :foos

# foo.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
```

When I do:

```rb
User.first.company.foos.build
# => id: nil, user_id: nil, company_id: 1, ...
```

Why `user_id` is `nil`?

This is in a controller. Do I have to use `.tap` or `.merge`:

```rb
User.first.company.foos.build(foo_params.merge({ user_id: 1 })
```

Or:

```rb
User.first.company.foos.build(foo_params.tap { |par| par[:user_id] = 1 })
```

I expect the `build` to have both `user_id` and `company_id` filled with the model's primary_key.

Comment: When you're buiding off an association Rails will only ever fill a single foreign key. It doesn't keep track of the whole chain that you called it from. Neither should it as what you're doing is a pretty blatant violation of the rule of Demeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've went the Domain-Driven Design approach with this:

```rb
# company.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :foos

def build_foos(args = {})
 foos.build({user_id: user_id}.merge(args))
end
```

In controller:

```rb
User.first.company.build_foos

# or

User.first.company.build_foos(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `user_id` is `nil?`

Because when you call `User.first.company.foos.build`

It runs `User.first` first

example: `#<User id: 1, company_id: 1, ...`
equivalent to:

```
user = User.first
user.company.foos.build
```

And next, it gets the User above to continue running: `user.company`

equivalent to:

```
company = user.company # or company  = Company.find_by(user_id: 1)
company.foos.build
```

**so lastly what do I want to say?**

`User.first.company.foos.build`
equa to
`company.foos.build`

if `User.first.foos.build` => `user_id` not `nil`

if `Company.first.foos.build` => `company_id` not `nil`

in this case => `foos` was build from `company`

so what's your error?

redundant `has_many :foos` in `user.rb`

because User `has_one :company` and Company `has_many :foos` => of course user `has_many :foos`

## Solution

remove `has_many :foos` in `user.rb` and remove `belongs_to :user` in foo.rb

Comment: I believe the "user" should be passed to the `build` method and there's no other way around  it.It just looks messy in my controller. Maybe I need a DDD (Domain Driven Design) approach?

Comment: you don't need include user_id in foo because user_id include in company before,
you just need include company_id in your foo params

Comment: A user has many `foos` also. `has_many :foos` is needed in the user model. But I've figured it out. Many thanks for your contribution.